# AJAX call is failing, is the url path correct?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I am a beginner in web development (self learner),and I am trying to connect my javascript .js file to java servlet through AJAX where I am stuck. It's not making the AJAX call, or not entering the java code, returning to the call back function. Is my url mapping or path specified correct? Or can you see some other error? Thanks!

JS code:

```
    a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num"+ 0).value);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "/add?num1=" + a , true ); // true is for Asynchronous request
    alert("here3 a=" + a);
    xhr.send();
    var ret = eval(xhr.responseText); //just trial
    alert("eval" + ret);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { 
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            document.getElementbyId('ajaxResponse').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            var ret = eval(xhr.responseText);
            alert("Callback1 = " + ret); 
        } 
        else(alert("Callback failed"))
    };
```

Java servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {

    System.out.println("Add Servlet called");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
//  int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

//  int k = i+j;        

     PrintWriter out = res.getWriter(); 
     out.println("Result is i=" + i);
     res.setContentType("text/plain");
     res.getWriter().write(i);  
   }
```

Web.xml

(servlet): callJava 
          com.AddServlet

(servlet-mapping):callJava 
                  /add

It just goes in else condition of callback function ("Callback failed"). Also, does the location/folder structure of the servlet or js file matters, if mapping is done in .xml file? Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to know if your path is correct? Take a look at the DevTools, select "Network" tab and see what is the status of the AJAX call.

Comment: yes, that is what my question is. Does the folder structure matters if you map the servlet in .xml file and call through that in xhr.open() function?

Comment: *"Take a look at the DevTools, select "Network" tab and see what is the status of the AJAX call"* please answer this, @AnangDadhich. If you see the status is e.g. 404 instead of 200, then you already have your answer. 404 means "Page not found" which means your "URL path" is indeed wrong.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late response, I started facing some other issue. 
I just checked the status and it indeed is saying 404, thank you! I knew there was some problem with my url. What's the correct way to specify the path for this?
My folder structure in eclipse looks like:
Java Resources > src > com.project > AddServlet.java
Web Content> javascript > hello.js (my JS file)
Web Content > index.html
I am trying to call java from js. The thing is, when I call java from index.html, it works through .xml file, but not for .js. I did .../../ method also, but didn't work!

Comment: Here, src and Web Content are on same level.
xhr.open("GET", "../../src/com/project/AddServlet?num1=" + a , true ) didn't work.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, the url should just be "add?num1=" instead of "/add?num1=". It does map through .xml file! Now I am reaching java file and status is 200 :D 
Next I am trying to figure out how to return back value any ajax response value from java servlet to javascript file or html file. Should I do it somehow in xhr.onreadystatechange() function? It's still not satisfying both conditions [if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)]. Any suggestions?

Comment: When prefixing a path with `/`,  servers start to resolve the path from the document root directory. `./` (or nothing) means the current directory, i.e. it's the directory the page loaded the script is saved, not where the script itself is saved, and you seem already to know what `../` does. This ofcourse can be changed with mapping or server configurations, that's why I said we can't "_know if your path is correct_".

Comment: In addition to the other comments, consider that it is almost a standard to make your server work with absolute paths. Paths starting with '/' are to be considered absolute to the root of your server public files directory and any other path is to be considered relative to the current path (the current page path).

Comment: Thank you guys! My code is working now :D It still works through the mapping method. And with the above method of absolute path  xhr.open("GET", "../../src/com/project/AddServlet?num1=" + a , true ) , it still doesn't work. Do you see any error in this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really help you with the server side part as I'm not familiar with the framework that you are using. But the following are my recommendations for the client side code:

- Use `let` instead of `var`;
- `true` flag to make request async is not necessary because it is the default and will be soon deprecated.
- It is preferable to use the new `addEventListener` API instead of directly adding the handler to the intended target.
- Fully setup your request before calling `open` and `send`.
- Use `===` operator instead of `==`.

```
const a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num" + 0).value);
```

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', (e) => {
  if(e.target.readyState === 4){
    document.getElementbyId('ajaxResponse').innerHTML = e.target.responseText;  
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "/add?num1=" + a);
xhr.send();
```

Please let me know if it works. If it does, you may want to check if your server is correctly setting the "found" response code (200).

Comment: hello! thanks for your response! I did make the edits you suggested, and the code looks good! It still didn't make the ajax call, for which I believe the problem is in URL : "/add?num1=" . Also,  the response code is 404. Any suggestions what is the correct way to write the url path? Please check my comment above on my post, where I wrote the folder structure.

Comment: @AnangDadhich could you please post your full web.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, the url should just be "add?num1=" instead of "/add?num1=". It does map through .xml file! Now I am reaching java file and status is 200 :D 
Next I am trying to figure out how to return back value any ajax response value from java servlet to javascript file or html file. Should I do it somehow in xhr.onreadystatechange() function? It's still not satisfying both conditions [if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)]. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use comments or edit your question to tell others about your progress or to add any other information